# Refactoring legacy synchronous Python code

Tags: python, asynchronous, refactoring

I am in the process of trying to refactor some Python code that looks something like the following:-

```
1) if condition1:
2)      lookupID = showSomeModalForm()
3)      result = dbLookUp(lookUpID)
     if result == 3:
        doSomething(result)
        value = showSomeModalForm2()
elif condition2:
     id = showSomeModalForm()
     doSomethingInDB(id)
     id = 0
```

Currently, as you can see there are several places where a modal form is shown - as soon as the modal form returns the code underneath the relevant if (nested if) is executed. So for example as soon as line 2) returns line 3) will be executed

I am involved in some work that will mean that in some circumstances the code will be synchronous and shown as a modal form as now but in other circumstances it will be an asynchronous call.

To start with I have replaced all calls to showModalForm* to point to a callback function called askForInput like below. askForInput will be implemented in both the synchronous and asynchronous cases.

```
def refactor(self):
   4)  if condition1:
   5)     lookupID = askForInput()
   6)     result = dbLookUp(lookUpID)
   7)     if result == 3:
   8)        doSomething(result)
   9)        value = askForInput()
  10)        value += 2
   10)  elif condition2:
  11)     id = askForInput()
  12)     doSomethingInDB(id)
   13)    id = 0
```

This works fine if the code is synchronous because the code will excute line 1) assuming condition1 is true it will then execute line 2) and once something is chosen it will execute line 3)

As this is legacy code this set of if's (nested ifs) encodes a lot of logic that needs to stay and I am unsure how to refactor it if the call to askForInput was asynchronous. So for example, if an asynchronous call was made at line 5) I would want it to return back to the refactor method and resume execution at line 6). If the async call was at line 9) I would want the code to resume at line 10) and 11) would go to 12).

Originally, I thought I could do this using a callback and sending the refactor method as the argument - however this would start execution back at the top and what I want to do is almost pause keep the state of the refactor method call the askForInput method and return control back to the refactor method exactly below where askForInput was called.

Reading around I started to think this might have something to do with generators and co-routines but I am not sure if I am barking up the wrong tree.

Any help on how to refactor this could would be extremely appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using any particular asynchronous library now (eg twisted/gevent)?

Comment: @Gerrat, the code is plain Python for now. No async library at present. Not out the question to use one though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use threading - something like:

```
import threading, time

def askForInput(arg):
    arg.append("some ID")
    time.sleep(2)

def main():
    print("starting time: {}".format(time.asctime()))
    my_input = []  # want an argument we can mutate
    thr = threading.Thread(target=askForInput, args=(my_input,))
    thr.start()
    thr.join()  # will wait here
    lookupID = my_input[0]
    print("ending time: {}".format(time.asctime()))
    print("Result back from async call: {}".format(lookupID))

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    main()
```

Results:

```
starting time: Thu Oct 31 10:32:51 2013
ending time: Thu Oct 31 10:32:53 2013
Result back from async call: some ID
```